# Playing a byte array from a file

Tags: android, arrays, audiotrack

I'm trying to play byte array stored in a text file using AudioTrack in android. The byte array is formed from the recording using AudioDispatcher (from TarsosDSP library). I'm required to record multiple times, hence, I'm appending the byte array to the same text file. After the recording is done,I'm not able to play the byte file for the entire recording (which consists of the byte file from the multiple recording). But, I'm able to play the byte array from a single recording.

Here is the code for playing the byte file using AudioTrack

```
    byte bytePlay[] = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file1);
        Log.i("byte",bytePlay.length+"");
        ShortBuffer sBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
        final short[] shorts = new short[sBuf.capacity()];
        sBuf.get(shorts);

        AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                16000, //hard coded! not ideal
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                shorts.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.play();
        // Write the music buffer to the AudioTrack object
        audioTrack.write(shorts, 0, shorts.length);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the code where I'm appending data to the file

```
 File file1 = new File(file_name);
                    if (!file1.exists()) {
                        try {
                            file1.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file1,true);
                        fos.write(bytePlayRec);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a "text" file. Why not create a separate file for each record instead? Or alternatively, put some marker to separate each record and loop through them.

Comment: I would have created a separate file but the number of recordings is very large in some cases. Hence, I didn't opt for that. Can you please let me know what you mean by a separate marker for each record?

Comment: I don't see what's the matter with creating a lot of files. In your case it's much better than one single very big file. By a marker I mean something in the file that let's you know when one recording ends. Ideally you should have a header for each recording with information about that recording, specially the length, so you can know when one recording starts and when it ends so you can play it. Still best solution for me is one file per recording. Code to handle it will be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that. Also, is there away where I can convert the byte array file into an mp3 file? I tried writing the present byte array into a .mp3 file and playing it using MediaPlayer but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's off-topic, but I'll answer: of course it doesn't work. Changing the file extension won't change the contents. MP3 is a compressed format. You need to use an MP3 encoding/decoding library to convert to/play MP3.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I shall look up for such a library and try it.